# Kafka producer - Cannot append records to read-only mirror topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I running a producer and raising an exception with the following code.

```
    @GetMapping("/send")
    public ResultVo send(@RequestParam(value = "content") String content) {
        return new ResultVo(kafkaTemplate.send("hello-topic", 0, "test", content));
    }
```

```
2023-08-07 21:00:12.330 ERROR 1508 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='test' and payload='test content' to topic hello-topic and partition 0:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidRequestException: Cannot append records to read-only mirror topic
```

Although the producer not work, I wrote an consumer and can get message normally.

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "hello-topic", groupId = "hello-group")
    public void handleMessage(String content) {
         log.info("{}", content);
    }
```

Comment: As the error says, the topic is "read-only", so yes, a consumer will work (however, you show using a completely different topic), but a producer will not... I suggest asking your cluster admins why that is (perhaps there is an ACL on the topic)

Comment: Thank you OneCricketeer. There should be ACL on the topic, let me ask my cluster admin first.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I changed to another topic, and send/receive OK. Just that topic don't have permission to publish. Maybe not tech issue, it should be just a permission issue. Thanks very much!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer below using the checkmark next to the post it it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

[Mirror topics are read only](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/multi-dc-deployments/cluster-linking/mirror-topics-cp.html)

You need to find where they are being mirrored from, then produce to that cluster/topic, instead.